# Pressed FN + ALTGR, and now my keyboard is messed up

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

**FYI:** I have a [Svive Triton TKL](https://www.svive.gg/products/triton-gaming-keyboard-tkl/).

I pressed <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> then G on my keyboard started to blink, I didn't think much about it, and before I knew it it had stopped blinking. Suddenly:

- Can't type `s`.
- Pressing <kbd>s</kbd> twice makes `j`
- Keyboard suddenly types `asldlkaslkd` out of nowhere
- Can't press <kbd>s</kbd>

Does anyone know what my problem is? I have tested the keyboard with another PC and I have the same problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [short manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1576574/Svive-Triton.html?page=5#manual) and it reads (formatting added, typos corrected for readability):

> #### Macro Record
>
> You can also configure your own macros for your keyboard. Use the following steps:
>
> 1. Press <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>R-Alt</kbd> to start Macro Record process, Gmode Led will flash.
> 2. Type any key you want to record.
> 3. Press <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>R-Alt</kbd> again, Gmode Led will flash more quickly.
> 4. Assign a key you want to save this record.
> 5. Gmode LED will stop flashing, Macro record process finished.
>
> Notice: <kbd>FN</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> keys can't be assigned to macro key.
>
> #### Hardware Reset
>
> If the keyboard has unexpected problem, you can reset the keyboard by holding <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> for 3 seconds. LED will flash once and current profile will be reset to default setting.

Unfortunately it doesn't state how to delete one particular macro without affecting other settings. I would try to record a new macro that assigns `s` to <kbd>s</kbd>. If this doesn't solve the problem use the reset procedure.

There are other pages with keystrokes you may find interesting.

Comment: Thanks, just restarted the keyboard and it worked